# Symfony2 HTTP cache: is there a way to ignore query parameters when generating the cache?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, http-caching

I found a post outlining how to [exclude parameters from the cache for Symfony 1.4](http://www.pyrkosz.pl/Symfony_Ignore_unused_GET_parameters_for_caching.html) and I would like to do something similiar for Symfony 2.3.

When using say Adwords a bunch of query parameters will be included in the uri that have nothing to do with the rendering of the page `[gclid, x, y, utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_content]` and I would like a way to tell the Symfony2 cache that the following pages are the same and cache them as one page:

- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com?gclid=1`

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't let users see these query params. Instead use a filter and redirect to plain url.

Comment: Wouldn't these variables need to be collected by the Google Analytics scripts? That would mean a javascript redirect would be required no?

Comment: Are you doing something on the server side with this specific query params?

Comment: No but I am wary of javascript redirects. I mean the solution that comes to mind here is creating a kernel response listener and if these query params exist in the uri stripping them and serving a javascript redirect to the intended page for every page on my site. I think I would investigate other caching technologies like Varnish before I implemented that. If it was just a server side redirect I would be more open to the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Symfony2 AppCache and not Varnish. AppCache is a php reverse proxy : it caches an URI response and process headers.
Obviously, the following uris :

- http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com?gclid=1

are different, so the trick will be to make them equals for the reverse proxy. 
You can do that on many levels :

- on the web server
- on the `Request` object
- on the AppCache Storage

IMO the easier solution is to remove them from `Request` at creation. The following code do the trick directly in app.php, if you want you can do the same with a subclass of Request object but you will have to deal with boostrap.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
//Modify query string here
$qs = $request->server->get('QUERY_STRING');
if ('' != $qs) {

    $parts = array();

    foreach (explode('&', $qs) as $chunk) {

        $param = explode("=", $chunk);

        if (!$param || !in_array($param[0], array('gclid', 'x', 'y', 'utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_content'))) {
            $parts[] = $chunk;
        }
    }
    $request->server->set('QUERY_STRING', implode('&', $parts));
}
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: It would have been easier to use [`parse_str($string, array $output)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0):

Based on LFIs answer, I simplified the whole construct a little bit (AppBundle::CACHE_SKIP_PARAMS contains the array of skipped parameters):

```
// Exclude irrelevant parameters
$qs = $request->server->get('QUERY_STRING');

if ('' != $qs)
{

    parse_str($qs, $params);

    if (is_array($params) && !empty($params))
    {
        $relevantParams = [];

        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!in_array($key, \AppBundle\AppBundle::CACHE_SKIP_PARAMS))
            {
                $relevantParams[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $params = $relevantParams;
    }

    $request->server->set('QUERY_STRING', implode('&', $params));
}
```